# Finding the closest data point in a sequential list

Tags: c#

Given a `List<double>` and a `double`, it will find the closest value and return the index of the closest value in the list. The list will always be in order.

```
private int FindClosestPoint(double val, List<Double> list)
{
    int ret = new int();

    int max = list.Count;
    int min = 0;
    int index = max / 2;

    while (max - min > 1)
    {
        if (val < list[index])
            max = index;
        else if (val > list[index])
            min = index;
        else
            return index;

        index = (max - min) / 2 + min;
    }

    if (max != list.Count && min != 0)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(list[max] - val) < Math.Abs(list[min] - val))
            ret = max;
        else
            ret = min;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Bug

Suppose `list[0] = 0`, `list[1] = 1`, and `val = 2`.  After doing the binary search, you are left with `min = 1` and `max = 2`.

When we get here:

> ```
> if (max != list.Count && min != 0)
> ```

the block is skipped because `max == list.Count`.  This is correct because you don't want to deference `list[max]`.  However, you end up returning `ret` which was never set and still contains `0`.  The correct index to return would be `1`.

I believe you can fix your function by eliminating the `ret` variable and returning `min` instead.  In other words:

```
private int FindClosestPoint(double val, List<Double> list)
{
    int max = list.Count;
    int min = 0;
    int index = max / 2;

    while (max - min > 1)
    {
        if (val < list[index])
            max = index;
        else if (val > list[index])
            min = index;
        else
            return index;

        index = (max - min) / 2 + min;
    }

    if (max != list.Count &&
            Math.Abs(list[max] - val) < Math.Abs(list[min] - val))
    {
        return max;
    }
    return min;
}
```

#### Strange way to initialize an int

Also I noticed this strange line:

> ```
> int ret = new int();
> ```

I'm not sure why you didn't just initialize `ret` the same way as you did with `min`:

```
int ret = 0;
```

The two statements are equivalent but since `int` is a value type, the former statement is odd because it makes it look like you are trying to allocate an object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is correct but is doe not match what I am used to seeing
[Binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)
You can move the index 1 more as you know that position is not correct
`Max` should start at `Count - 1`
I think it would be cleaner to check if target is outside the array up front

```
int M;
int L = 0;
int R = A.Length - 1;
while (L <= R)
{
    M = (L + R) / 2;
    if      (A[M] < T) L = M + 1;
    else if (A[M] > T) R = M - 1;
    else return M;
}
```